# Prove that $M$ is similar to a $n\times n$ real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a diagonalizable complex $n\times n$ matrix such that $M$ is similar to its complex conjugate $\overline{M}$. Prove that $M$ is similar to a $n\times n$ real matrix.

My work:

$\overline{M}=g^{-1}Mg$ for some invertible complex $n\times n$ matrix $g$. Now $M+\overline{M}$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix. Then $g(M+\overline{M})g^{-1}=gMg^{-1}+g\overline{M}g^{-1}=gMg^{-1}+M$. I was stuck afterwards. What I can do here with the diagonalizability of $M$? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Ya I know I haven't used it. That's why I asked how to use it here.

Comment: *Hints:* 1) Similarity is a (equivalence relation) transitive relation i.e. if $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C$ then $A \sim C$ where $\sim$ is the similarity  2) Similar matrices have the same set of eigenvalues.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani, in fact your tip is not quite useful since it does not work for the matrix $\text{diag}[1+i, 1-i]$.

Comment: @Jihad well, if you follow your example with my hints, you'll find that complex eigenvalues of $M$ should come in conjugate pairs corresponding to rotations!

Comment: Ehsan is referring to the [real Jordan form](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/realjord.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is diagonalizable, so we can assume :$M\sim\mathrm{diag}\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\},u_n\in C$
since $M\sim \overline{M}$ so $M\sim\mathrm{diag}\{\overline{u_1},\cdots,\overline{u_n}\}$
this show $\forall k\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ we can always find a $t\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ satisfy $u_t=\overline{u_k}$ . now let $M\sim\mathrm{diag}\{s_1,\overline{s_1},\cdots,s_r,\overline{s_r},t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_{n-2r}\}$ where $t_i\in R,s_k=a_k+ib_k\notin R$. 
notice that :
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
i&1\\
1&i
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a+bi&0\\
0&a-bi
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
i&1\\
1&i
\end{array}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&-b\\
b&a
\end{array}\right)$$
so we have:
$$M\sim\mathrm{diag}\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_1&-b_1\\
b_1&a_1
\end{array}\right),\cdots,\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_r&-b_r\\
b_r&a_r
\end{array}\right),t_1,\cdots,t_{n-2r}\}$$
done.

Comment: How did you take $M$ as $M\sim\mathrm{diag}\{s_1,\overline{s_1},\cdots,s_r,\overline{s_r},t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_{n-2r}\}$ where $t_i\in R,s_k=a_k+ib_k\notin R$?